# Finding an analytic function in terms of $z$ only

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the full question:
Find a real valued function $v:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the function $f=u+iv$ is an analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$, if $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the harmonic function defined by
$$u(x,y) = x^4 - 6x^2 y^2 + y^4 + 4xy$$
Assume $u$ is harmonic.
Express this function $f$ in terms of $z:= x+iy$ only.

So I found the function $f$ to be
$$f(x+iy) = x^4 - 6x^2 y^2 + y^4 + 4xy + i(4x^3 y - 4xy^3 + 2y^2 - 2x^2 + C)$$
where $C \in \mathbb{C}$.
It looks like $f$ was $f(z) = z^4 + D$ where $D = iC \in \mathbb{C}$ but I quickly realised that $z^4$ would only have 6 terms where $f$ has $8$.
Is there a way to see what the function is? I can't seem to see it.

Comment: Does your $f$ fulfil the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Compute $z^4-2iz^2$

Comment: Yup. I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that if $u$ is some harmonic function then there exists an analytic function $f$ with $u$ as its real part

Comment: That's odd: there's a $-4x$ there that's the only linear term....

Comment: Sorry, it should be the primitive of that, so $-2x^2$.

Comment: @uSir470888 That worked; how did you see that?

Comment: Polynomials are closed under differentiation and integration. If the real part is a polynomial the whole thing is a polynomial. Finally, if you want to write a polynomial in the basis $1,z,z^2,z^3,...$ you just eliminate terms starting from highest degree down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try and guess the answer directly. Note that $u$ is a polynomial in $x,y$ of degree four so $f$ should be a polynomial in $z$ of degree four. Guessing $f = z^4$, we get that

$$ \operatorname{Re}(f) = \operatorname{Re}((x + iy)^4) = x^4 + y^4 - 6x^2y^2 $$

so we got already three terms but missed $4xy$. How can we get $xy$? This is a second degree polynomial so we can try $z^2$. Since

$$ z^2 = (x + iy)^2 = x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy $$

we see that $\operatorname{Re}(-2i z^2) = 4xy$. Hence, if we take $f(z) := z^4 - 2i z^2$, we get 
$$\operatorname{Re}(f) = x^4 + y^4 - 6x^2y^2 + 4xy. $$

Obviously, we can add to $f$ any constant $iC$ where $C \in \mathbb{R}$ without changing the real part or the analyticity of $f$. Now check if this coincides with your result.

Comment: Thank you. A small question -- why is the constant $iC$ (a purely imaginary constant)? Could it also be say $2+i$ instead?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours: If you replace $f$ with $f + (2 + i)$ then $\operatorname{Re}(f + (2 + i)) = \operatorname{Re}(f) + \operatorname{Re}(2 + i) = \operatorname{Re}(f) + 2$ so the real part will change.

Comment: Ah so it's because we defined the real part as $u$ already defined right? So having some constant like $2+i$ would still keep $f$ as being analytic?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours: Yeah. You can add any complex constant (or any other analytic function) and the result will still be analytic but if you add a constant which has a non-zero real part, the real part won't be $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $x^4 - 6x^2y^2 + y^4 + i4x^3y - i4xy^3$ i.e. $x^4 + 4x^3(iy) + 6x^2(iy)^2 + 4x(iy)^3 + y^4$, is just $(x+iy)^4 = z^4$.

The remaining term is $4xy + i(2y^2 - 2x^2) = -2i(x^2 + 2ixy -y^2) =-2iz^2 $

So $f(z) = z^4 - 2iz^2$.